# javascript string character manipulation

Tags: javascript, string, fromcharcode

My challenge is to create a function that takes in a string and returns a new string with each character advanced 1 space of the alphabet.  Ex: "hello" returns "ifmmp."

I haven't yet wrapped my code in a function.  This will get me the first new character but I can't figure out how to move through the rest of the new characters.

```
var str = "hello";

var numStr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    numStr.push((str.charCodeAt(i) + 1));

}

var newStr = String.fromCharCode(numStr[0]);

//returns "i"
```

Comment: You may use `+` operator to add strings so `'a' + 'b'` gives you `'ab'`. Use a for loop to build `newStr` like `var newStr = ''; for (var i = 0; ....) { newStr += String.fromCharCode(numStr[i]); }`. `newStr += x` is like `newStr = newStr + x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use `fromCharCode()`.  Creating a function could look something like this:

**JavaScript**

```
var str = "hello";

function incrementStringLetters(s) {
    var newStr = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        newStr += String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(i)+1);
    }
    return newStr;
}


console.log(incrementStringLetters(str))
```

**Output**

> ifmmp

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/f0vy3h9v/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!  I couldn't figure out how to use the fromCharCode function like this.

Answer (score 0):

Another proposal with:

- [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`String.fromChatCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)
- [`String#charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)
- [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var str = "hello",
    newStr = str.split('').map(function (a) {
        return String.fromCharCode(a.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    }).join('');

document.write(newStr);
```